# Foreach en Laravel que te separe los resultado con comas

Tags: laravel, foreach

Hola buenas estoy iterando unos datos y quiero que me los separe con ','. Hasta ahora lo estaba haciendo así:

```
{{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
```

Tengo tres apartado donde itero datos distintos:

```
              <div>
                <h5>Genero:</h5>
                <span>
                  @foreach ($pro->variaciones as $item)
                    @if ($item->variant == 'genero')
                        {{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
                        {{ $item->valor }}
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
                </span>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5>Tallas:</h5>
                <span>
                  @foreach ($pro->variaciones as $item)
                    @if ($item->variant == 'tallas')
                        {{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
                        {{ $item->valor }}
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
                </span>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5>Colores:</h5> 
                <span>
                  @foreach ($pro->variaciones as $item)
                    @if ($item->variant == 'colores')
                        {{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
                        {{ $item->valor }}
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
                </span>
              </div>
```

El problema es que el segundo y tercer foreach, me pone una coma también al principio, ejp(, blanco , morado).

Y otra pregunta así aprovecho, como puedo hacer que si no hay resultados en Genero(ejp) no me muestre el div completo??? Si lo hago con el foreach, pero si existe me repite el titulo varias veces según resultados.

De este modo hago la consulta:

```
$productos = Product::with('variaciones')

        ->join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategoria', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('marcas', 'products.proveedor', '=', 'marcas.id')
        ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria', 'subcategories.name as nameSubcategoria', 'marcas.empresa as proveedor')
        ->latest('id')
        ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: ¿No sería mas simple mandar con ese formato los datos desde que se compone la consulta?

Comment: No se como hacer lo que dices! Traer los datos ya construidos? @BetaM

Comment: Hola @BetaM he añadido como hago la consulta, es que no entiendo lo que quieres decir